How to pass TDataSet as TADOStoredProc parameter
Attention: Following question: How to pass DataSet: TDataSet as procedure parameter is about completely different topic.
I would like to have a set of dynamic attributes for an entity in Microsoft SQL Server database.
It is pretty clear how I will store them. It is clear how they will be presented as a collection in a Delphi object.
It is unclear how I will pass them to the DBMS.
Instead of making separate stored procedure calls for each attribute and then call a delete procedure to remove deleted ones, I would like to pass a whole set of attributes over a stored procedure parameter at once to do all the processing in it internally.
One option to pass all the dynamic attributes over a parameter is to serialize them into XML or JSON and pass over an @Attr NVARCHAR(MAX) parameter. I even found an open source user defined function to parse JSON on the SQL Server side and it works.
But then I found an ability to pass a user defined type as a parameter and would like to give it a try:
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[DynamicAttributeType] AS TABLE(
    [Element_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SequenceNo] [int] NULL,
    [Parent_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Object_ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](2000) NULL,
    [StringValue] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [ValueType] [varchar](10) NOT NULL
)

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Goods_Save]
    @ID INT,
    @Name NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Attr DynamicAttributeType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    -- Put the code here
END

It compiles well, but there is a problem: how to pass data to the @Attr parameter on the Delphi side?
I tried ftDataSet parameter type (I am using Delphi 6):
procedure TForm1.AddFieldDef(AMemTable: TKbmMemTable; AName: WideString;
  AType: TFieldType; ASize: Integer);
var
  fd: TFieldDef;
begin
  fd := AMemTable.FieldDefs.AddFieldDef();
  fd.Name := AName;
  fd.DataType := AType;
  fd.Size := ASize;
end;

procedure TForm1.AddAttribute(AMemTable: TKbmMemTable; AElement_ID: Integer;
  ASequenceNo, AParent_ID, AObject_ID: Variant;
  AName, AStringValue: WideString; AValueType: string);
begin
  AMemTable.Insert();
  AMemTable.FieldByName('Element_ID').AsInteger := AElement_ID;
  AMemTable.FieldByName('SequenceNo').Value := ASequenceNo;
  AMemTable.FieldByName('Parent_ID').Value := AParent_ID;
  AMemTable.FieldByName('Object_ID').Value := AObject_ID;
  TWideStringField(AMemTable.FieldByName('Name')).Value := AName;
  TWideStringField(AMemTable.FieldByName('StringValue')).Value := AStringValue;
  AMemTable.FieldByName('ValueType').AsString := AValueType;
  AMemTable.Post();
end;

procedure TForm1.SaveButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  ads: TkbmMemTable;
  sp: TADOStoredProc;
begin
  ads := TkbmMemTable.Create(Self);
  sp := TADOStoredProc.Create(Self);
  try
    AddFieldDef(ads, 'Element_ID', ftInteger, 0);
    AddFieldDef(ads, 'SequenceNo', ftInteger, 0);
    AddFieldDef(ads, 'Parent_ID', ftInteger, 0);
    AddFieldDef(ads, 'Object_ID', ftInteger, 0);
    AddFieldDef(ads, 'Name', ftWideString, 2000);
    AddFieldDef(ads, 'StringValue', ftWideString, 10000);
    AddFieldDef(ads, 'ValueType', ftString, 10);
    ads.CreateTable();
    ads.Open();
    AddAttribute(ads, 1, Null, Null, Null, 'energy-kcal_100g', '540', 'string');
    AddAttribute(ads, 2, Null, Null, Null, 'energy-kj_100g', '2251', 'string');
    AddAttribute(ads, 3, Null, Null, Null, 'fat_100g', '34', 'string');
    AddAttribute(ads, 4, Null, Null, Null, 'monounsaturated-fat_100g', '28.6', 'string');
    AddAttribute(ads, 5, Null, Null, Null, 'polyunsaturated-fat_100g', '2.7', 'string');
    AddAttribute(ads, 6, Null, Null, Null, 'proteins_100g', '6', 'string');
    AddAttribute(ads, 7, Null, Null, Null, 'salt_100g', '1.6', 'string');
    AddAttribute(ads, 8, Null, Null, Null, 'sodium_100g', '0.64', 'string');
    AddAttribute(ads, 9, Null, Null, Null, 'sugars_100g', '1.7', 'string');

    sp.Connection := Conn;
    sp.ProcedureName := 'Goods_Save';
    sp.Parameters.CreateParameter('@ID', ftInteger, pdInput, 0, 150);
    sp.Parameters.CreateParameter('@Name', ftWideString, pdInput, 4000, 'The food');
    // Cannot pass "ads" as value here
    sp.Parameters.CreateParameter('@Attr', ftDataSet, pdInput, 0, Null);
    sp.ExecProc();
  finally
    sp.Free();
    ads.Free();
  end;
end;

How to pass the attributes data set ads as a parameter?

If you were using a .NET-based SqlClient, or an ODBC driver, you would specify a Structured DbType on the parameter. Since I believe the TADO objects wrap ActiveX Data Objects, which predate table types, you may not be able to do this.
